# Android - is there a way to have a 2-column row layout and tell which column a user presses?

Tags: android, android-layout

In a 2-column row layout, is there a way to tell which of the columns the user clicked or pressed on?

If the second column can be a button, it would be even better, but I am not sure how to make it into a button.  Here is what I am doing:

```
private List<HashMap<String, String>> fillMaps;
private SimpleAdapter simple_adapter;
ListView list = null;
```

and later:

```
    list = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // My data
    fillMaps = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    simple_adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, fillMaps, R.layout.comment_list,
            new String[] {"train", "from"}, 
            new int[] {R.id.TRAIN_CELL,  R.id.FROM_CELL });

    // This was the middle item R.id.FROM_CELL,
    list.setAdapter(simple_adapter);        
    list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
```

and I populate the list like this:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < obj.length(); i++ )
                            {
                                JSONObject o = obj.getJSONObject(i);
                                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                                ... Some variables set here...


                                map.put("train", comment);
                                map.put("from", "Edit");

                                fillMaps.add(map);

                                discussion.add( d );
                            }
                        }

                        simple_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Here is the comment_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:paddingTop="4dip"
 android:paddingBottom="6dip"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:textSize="13sp"
 android:weightSum="1.0"
 android:orientation="horizontal">

 <TextView android:id="@+id/TRAIN_CELL"
     android:textSize="16sp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="275dip"/>



  <TextView android:id="@+id/FROM_CELL"
     android:textSize="16sp"
     android:textStyle="bold"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_width="50dip"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try using some clickable items in the two columns of the row and handle those click events.

Suppose give two buttons in those two columns and add setOnClickListeners to them and finally check which button is click in the activity

Comment: that is a good idea, but I could not figure out how to place a button in the second column :) ..so far I can only get text to render :)

Comment: Can i know which layout you are using?

Comment: I have a question here about what I was trying to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12392799/android-what-data-structure-should-i-use-for-a-2-col-row-layout-with-1row-an-i

Comment: I just updated my original question with the code for how I populate the data.

Comment: what does this R.layout.comment_list contain?
I mean the xml file layout

Comment: well you are having a textviews.Make them buttons and they become clickable

Comment: yeah, sounds good, but I am not sure how to do that :) I kept trying different things to make them buttons/images but couldnt' get it right

Comment: Would you be able to post some code as an example for how to switch what I currently have to a button?

Comment: I didn't really change anything in the Java code, just changing the xml rendered the button :)

Comment: actually adding this crashed the page on the second line of this snippet:         Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.FROM_BUTTON);   
        btn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() 
        { 
         public void onClick(View arg0) 
            { 
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello click: " , 
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            } 
        });

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:paddingTop="4dip"
 android:paddingBottom="6dip"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:textSize="13sp"
 android:weightSum="1.0"
 android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/TRAIN_CELL"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:textSize="16sp"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/FROM_CELL"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/label_grid_view" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Be back if you have any issues

Comment: I am trying it now, but I think in the actual code, that wouldn't work because it references text fields...no?

Comment: Yes simply the id's and the textviews to buttons in your activity file too(java file)

Comment: Thank you! I got the button to render, but how do I give it a click listener and recognize which of the buttons in the list got clicked?

Comment: try using btn.setOnclickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
Toast.makeText(, "clicked ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
   }
  }));
Where btn is the name of the button in your activity

Comment: sorry, still a bit confused....I actually never declare that button in the code....it just somehow appeared once I changed the layout :) ....where in the code that I have above would I reference the button?

Comment: Where did you referred the textView replace it with button

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16615/discussion-between-genadinik-and-sharath-g)

Comment: ok i will be again at the same time today we will discuss there